# How to make .ssh/config file Hostname configurable

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-config

I am trying to set up `~/.ssh/config` file and want to make the hostname configurable

```
ssh pe1-cl1-bo1 should resolve to perf1-client1.app.bo1.host.in
ssh pe1-c2-bo3 should resolve to perf1-client2.app.bo3.host.in

i.e 
pe -> expands to perf
cl -> expands to client
bo -> remains as it s
```

I just want one entry in my ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host $1-$2-$3
    Hostname $1.$2..$3
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do it?? I tried using `ProxyCommand` but am unable to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in `ssh_config`. There are no mechanisms to do this substitution. But you should be able to write `bash` function to do that parsing for you.